# problem with countif function with multiple statements giving #value! error with nested if statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a problem with multiple if statments d2:d60 is colours while c2:C60 is dates and im check how many of each color is sold between the two dates

i have tried different ways round but it is not working only giving me #VALUE! error

i have tried using the show calculation steps but this is not working

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D60,"blue",C2:C60,"<="&F5,C2:C60,">="&F6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See an example of what you want to achieve:

[image]

The formula in the example is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A11:A14,">="&D10,A11:A14,"<="&E10,B11:B14,"red")
```

Make sure the dates are not saved as text.